# Memory regions of Java program?

Tags: java

I haven't deep dive into how Java treats memory when a program is running as I have been in working at application level. I recently had one instance in which I needed to know owing to performance issues of application.

I have been aware of "stack" , "heap" regions of memory and I thought this is the model of a Java program. However, it turns out that it is much more, and beyond that.

For example, I came across terms like: Eden, s0, s1, Old memory and so on. I was *never aware of these terminologies* prior.

As Java is / have been changing and so may be these terminologies are/aren't relevant as of Java 8.

Can anyone guide where to get this information and under what circumstance we need to know them? Are these part of main memory that is **RAM**.

Comment: Note that the [Java Memory Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_memory_model) (mentioned in the original tags) doesn't actually care about those terms, but describes how memory access works in a multi-processor environment in Java (keywords: read/write barriers, happens-before, ...).

Comment: @JoachimSauer: Thanks so much for your info. So JMM tag was about "read/write" and NOT the model of memory a java program sees?

Comment: Well, it *is* about a model of what Java sees in memory (hence the name), but it isn't a "this is everything that Java knows about memory" model and doesn't care about the distinction of heap or stack (or any of the others you mention).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java, as defined by the [Java Language Specification and the Java Virtual Machine Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/) talks about the **stack** and the **heap** (as well as the [method area](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se13/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.5.4)).

Those are the things that are needed to describe, conceptually, what makes a Java Virtual Machine.

If you wanted to implement a JVM you'd need to implement those in some way. They are just as valid in Java 13 as they were back in Java 1. Nothing has fundamentally changed about how those work.

The other terms you mentioned (as well as "old gen", "new gen", ...) are memory areas used in the implementation of **specific** garbage collection mechanisms, specifically those of implemented in the Oracle JDK / OpenJDK.

All of those areas are basically *specific parts of the heap*. The exact way the heap is split into those areas is up to the garbage collector to decide and knowing about them shouldn't be necessary unless you want to tweak your garbage collector.

Since garbage collectors change between releases and new garbage collector approaches are implemented regularly (as this is one of the primary ways to speed up JVMs), the concrete terms used here will change over the years.

Comment: Thanks Joachim Sauer for your answer.  So if I don't consider Garbage collector (for a moment), then memory is just "RAM" and it is divided as "Stack" and "Heap"?

Comment: Yes, it's basically a question of "how deep do you want to dig". From a high level perspective the memory of a Java program is separated into "stack" and "heap". And if you dig deeper and look at a specific implementation you might end up finding that the heap is actually split into all of those other sections that matter mostly to the garbage collector.

Comment: Thanks Joachim Sauer for your reply. If I want to understand it, can you please let me know where to start. Of courser internet is there, but it has too much details which may / may not be correct. And I am just delving into this. Thanks for your time and sharing deep knowledge.

Comment: @CuriousMind: Karol has posted a nice list of relevant topics to investigate. I can't tell you anything other than "find out stuff about those". As far as I know there's no one single source that will teach you all of this.

Answer (score 4):

Eden, s0, s1, Old memory and other memory areas exist only in the context of the specific garbage collector implementation e.g. generational collectors like G1 will divide the heap into mentioned areas however non-generational collectors like ZGC will not.

Start by reviewing the main garbage collectors in the JVM:

- ParNew
- CMS
- G1
- ZGC / Shenandoah / Azul C4

and then try to understand related concepts:

- Thread-local allocation buffers (TLAB)
- Escape analysis
- String constant pools, string interning, string de-duplication
- Permanent generation vs Metaspace
- Object layout e.g. why `boolean` is not taking 1 bit (word tearing)
- Native memory e.g. JNI or off-heap memory access

I don't believe that there is a single website that will explain the full JVM memory management approach.

Comment: Thanks so much Karol for your reply and sharing your knowledge.